# devicePixelRatio on Chrome for Android affecting WebGLRenderer.setSize function

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, three.js, webgl

I've been testing mobile support for Three.js and have discovered a quirk when it comes to the setSize function and multiple views. Here's the scenario.

While loading the [webgl_multiple_views](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html) example on my Nexus 7 (Android OS 4.3) in the Chrome for Android (29.0.1547.59) the entire rendered window is mis-aligned as can be seen in this screenshot.

[image: screenshot_2013-09-03-11-43-40]

At first I suspected a setViewport related issue but after further inspection determined that the `WebGLRenderer.js` function `setSize` was attempting to correct the WebGL canvas context size by multiplying by the devicePixelRatio like so:

```
_canvas.width = width * this.devicePixelRatio;
_canvas.height = height * this.devicePixelRatio;
```

This to me, seems a perfectly reasonable approach, but the problem here is that with some Android devices the calculation is **seemingly** already implied by the system, causing a skewed scene.

I've found that by implying a default pixel ratio of **1** I can correct the issue, but I'm anticipating it will likely break a lot of properly behaving mobile devices. Here's the "fix" if you will:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: false, devicePixelRatio: 1 } );
```

My question is, has anyone else encountered this? Does anyone have a more consistent fix for generally scaling a canvas context so it respects device pixel ratio, but doesn't break some android devices?

Thank-you kindly for any advice/assistance.

Comment: My guess is it's actually the width and height that vary across device, not the devicePixelRatio specifically, but I haven't run into this before.

Comment: Indeed, so I wonder if appling devicePixelRatio is necessary at all? The browser will return the appropriate device dimensions, and deal with Pixel Ratio outside of the scope of a web application. It would be great if any folks with Android devices (with a none 1 devicePixelRatio) could share there experiences?

Answer (score 4):

Try this function. I have tested it extensively and it reports the correct device width, height and a computedPixelRatio for every device I have tried...

```
function getDeviceDimensions()                  // get the width and height ofthe viewing device based on its OS
{
    screenWidth = window.screen.width;                                                  // get the width
    screenHeight = window.screen.height;                                                // get the height 
    var computedPixelRatio =  (window.screen.availWidth / document.documentElement.clientWidth);                        // a more reliable measure of device pixel ratio due to android firefox bugs...
    computedPixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio >= computedPixelRatio ? window.devicePixelRatio : computedPixelRatio;  // select whichever value is larger between pixel ratio methods
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1)                                   // if the client is on an android system
    {
        screenWidth = screenWidth / computedPixelRatio;                                 // divide the reported width by the pixel ratio
        screenHeight = screenHeight / computedPixelRatio;                               // divide the reported height by the pixel ratio
    }
    //alert(screenWidth + " " + screenHeight + " " + window.devicePixelRatio + " " + computedPixelRatio);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this on my tablet when I get home.

Comment: Again, thanks for the attempt. Your code is indeed getting correct values for the window, but isn't getting me the correct canvas size. I now suspect it has to do specifically with Chrome and Safari. As Firefox on Android works fine. Here's my latest reading on the subject, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/ wonder if it has anything to do with this "Backing Store" business

Comment: Indeed, it is interesting that the reported pixelRatio is not necessarily the actual pixelRatio. This is what I've been seeing all over the place, exacerbating the issue. I suppose it's just a matter of time before the implementations start to sync up a bit better.